# corona sdk crashes when attempting to open a file using io.open

Tags: io, lua, coronasdk

I've never used corona sdk before and decided to create a key logger as a test to see if I liked corona.

I'm able to check input and specify the file path but once my code reaches io.open the simulater freezes and crashes and the input is not added to the text file.

I've looked just about every where I can think of for an answer and found none.

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient code out there. I'm a newbie to any type of programming outside of the ROBLOX engine.

```
    function WriteToFile(String)
        local path = system.pathForFile("R@T.txt",      system.DocumentsDirectory)
        print("Path") -- Just to try and determine the origin of the crash
        local File, ErrorString = io.open(path, "W")
        print("File") 
        if not File then
            print('File error: ' .. ErrorString)
        else
            print("else")
            File:write(String)
            io.close(File)
        end

        File = nil
     end

     function ReturnInput( Key )
         if Key.phase == 'down' then
         print(Key.keyName)
         WriteToFile(tostring(Key.keyName))
      end
   end

   Runtime:addEventListener('key', ReturnInput)
```

Comment: `io.open(path, "W")` "W" should be lowercase

Comment: I managed to figure this out already but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you this, but unfortunately you can not create keyloggers with Corona SDK. You can not create anything that runs on the background.

E.g. you can't make a floater widget and when you press it, you get screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was able to log the keys pressed using corona. I made it for fun not to be malicious so not being able to hide it or run it as a process didn't bother me.